# Autowire doesn't work on servlets

Tags: spring, servlets, autowired

I can't figure out why Autowired of DAOs classes works fine in Test classes but not in servlets. web.xml file load correctly context configuration as i can see by the log, so the problem must be in my applicationContext file.

This is my servlet:

```
@Controller
public class TestAutowired extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private IUserDao uDao;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        uDao.getUserById(1);
}
}
```

And this is my ApplicationContext (configuration.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Spring configuration -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation=...>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.firststepteam.dao">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.firststepteam.services">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.firststepteam.servlet">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!-- View resolver -> JSP -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -->
<bean id="placeHolder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:hostingData.conf" />
</bean>

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.db.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.db.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- JPA E HIBERNATE -->
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
  <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
  <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY -->
<bean id="dbEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fs_db" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="dbEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class = "org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet lifecycle is managed by the container, not Spring.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? I have to make changes to web.xml?

Comment: Use Spring Controllers and not a raw servlet.  Use the Spring DispatcherServlet to delegate to them appropriately.  Besides, DAOs don't belong in servlets.  The Spring idiom has a service layer that owns DAOs and knows about transactions and units of work.  Wire the DAO into a service, the service into a controller, and let the Spring DispatcherServlet route the requests.